# Delete empty row in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I delete rows that are blank. I only managed remove a row using  `deleteRow()` method, but I need to remove only empty ones.

```
<table  border="1">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>testing</td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>           
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: foreach($('table tr'), function(){ if($this.find('td').val()==''){ // your code here }})

Comment: Show us  your code and we will try to help you. One possible idea might be to check for `$('tr').text()==''`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

What we are doing is getting all of the `td` checking if they are empty and then removing them if they do not have any text inside.

```js
$("td").each(function() {
    if (this.innerText === '') {
     this.closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

```css
td {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This will delete the row if just one of its cell is empty, not if and only if everyone of its cell is empty, right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [deleteRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow) you can use [removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table tr').forEach(function(e, i) {
    if (e.textContent.trim().length == 0) { // if row is empty
        e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    }
})


// in jQuery: 
//$('table tr').filter((i, e) => e.textContent.trim().length == 0).remove();
```

```html
<table  border="1">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>testing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you